pass data between screens using react native expo router
I'm trying to pass the pressed product data to the product screen using RN expo route but I'm getting
TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefinedenter image description here
// Stack
    <Stack screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" />
      <Stack.Screen name="(prod)" />
    </Stack>


// Product Screen
const ProductScreen = props => {
  const getProduct = props?.route?.params?.item;
  console.log("Products ", getProduct);
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>ProductScreen</Text>
    </View>
  );
};


Below is the Expo Router documentation for you.
Passing parameters to the routes

import { router, useLocalSearchParams } from 'expo-router'

Using hook
onPress={() => {
          router.push({ pathname: "/", params: { post: "random", id, other } });
        }}

Link component
<Link
        href={{
          pathname: "/",
          params: { post: "random", id, other },
        }}
      >
        Go to Details
      </Link>

Getting the data in the destination route
 const { post,id, other } = useLocalSearchParams();


thank you so much your solution worked for me
